# How to Sort Excel Column S.T. Rows w/ Null/Empty Column Cell Go On Top?

Tags: sorting, excel, excel-2007, vba

I have several rows that have data and 'flags' that are raised adjacent to the data when a macro is run.
For example:
***First Name*** | ***Last Name*** |     ***Flag***

```
John  | Smith  | Needs a Bath 
Cindy | LuWho  | 
Bob   | Loblaw | Needs a Bath
```

**Goal:**
I want the rows w/o flags (ie where column C == NULL/Empty string) to be sorted to the top and then sort by column B by A->Z to get this:

> Cindy | LuWho | 
>  Bob | Loblaw | Needs a Bath 
>  John | Smith |
>   Needs a Bath

**What I've Tried:**
Using Excel 2007's 'Sort', I've done Sort By (Column C), Sort On (Values) Sort By (A to Z) and (Z to A). Both A to Z and Z to A result in the flagged rows on top, not the bottom.

Before:[image]
After:
[image]

I ultimately want the code, but I'm currently trying to figure out how to do it by hand so I can then get the code through Excel's 'Record Macro'.

Comment: Are you sure? I only have Excel 2010 but when I sort this Z to A, blanks are on top. When I sort A to Z, blanks at the bottom.  I would be surprised if they changed the way the `Sort` functionality works.

Comment: I tried it on 2007 and sorting A to Z gives the result you are expecting. I'm not sure what you did but you did it wrong :D

Comment: I've updated with images of process. Let me know if you're somehow going about this differently or have an idea what I'm doing 'wrong' here.

Comment: @David Zemens and @Alexandre, are you both using blank fields? The difference here is that Kurt is using a formula in Column C. If you replace your blank cells with `=""`, you can get the behavior Kurt describes.

Comment: @PowerUser hmm good catch. Sorting formulas is always a little bit problematic.  A helper column is probably the best way to do this, as you suggest.

Comment: Actually, I'm kind of hoping someone will post something simpler.  My answer works, but it feels like too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended coming up with a solution that IMO, is more elegant than @Poweruser 's creating another column, populating it, hiding it, and then using sort on the hidden column. My method utilizes font color changes based on conditional formatting and sorts off of that.

1. Select desired range of column that contains blank values you want to sort by
2. Use Conditional Formatting>New Rule>'Use a formula to determine which cells to format' and in the textbox use the formula `=IF(INDIRECT("RC",0)="",TRUE,FALSE)`
3. Select 'Format...', select 'Font' tab and change the Font color to something not black or 'Automatic', apply changes
4. Using 'Sort', have 'Sort By' be the column with the blank cells, 'Sort On' be 'Font Color', and for 'Order By' change Automatic to whatever color you selected and have it be 'On Top'

With a little bit of tinkering of the recorded macro, I got the following working code (which also sorts by value another column after sorting for the 'blank' cells):

```
For oRow = 2 To iFinalRow
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(oRow, 5).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=IF(INDIRECT(""RC"",0)="""",TRUE,FALSE)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Next oRow

'Sort
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Add(Range("E:E"), _
    xlSortOnFontColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(31, 73, 125)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.SORT.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("D1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.SORT
    .SetRange Range("A:F")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

Per my comment above, the problem is that you are using a formula that evaluates to an empty string. If the field was actually empty, you'd have the behavior you are looking for.

Here's a *dirty-but-it-works* approach:

1. Make a new column to the right. Use the formula `=IF(C2<>"",2,1)` and fill down.
2. Hide the column from prying eyes (just right-click on the grey column header at top to hide it)
3. Sort by this column instead of C.

Comment: Is there any way to make the field 'actually empty' starting out with what I have in the pictures? I would think 'deleting' the data in the cell would make it 'actually empty' but this doesn't seem to be the case as I just tried it.

Comment: I don't know of any worksheet functions to make a cell emptier than `""`.  Technically, you could write a macro to do it for you, but then you'd have to save it as a .xlsm, there'll be macro warnings, etc.  I recommend just doing the above approach. I've used it myself.

Comment: But I would ultimately use it in a macro in a pre-existing .xlsm so I have no qualms about getting a macro to make things 'actually empty' and then sort...

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to replace blanks with single quote (`'`) before sorting. It is not visible but it is not `NULL`. See the code example:

```
Public Sub Sort_blanks()

    Dim lastrow As Integer

    ' The number of the last row
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' Replace blanks with with single quote
    Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "'"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Sort
    Range("A:C").Sort key1:=Range("C:C"), key2:=Range("B:B"), _
        order1:=xlAscending, order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```